# May one drink Diet Coke owned by a Jew and not sold over Pesach?

Tags: passover, chametz-leaven, employment

If someone works for a firm owned by a Jew who presumably does not sell the chametz, as he is totally secular, may one drink Diet Coke from that fridge?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya! Consider taking the following [short tour](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn more about the site. This site is not intended for _pesak_ practical ruling, so when in doubt consult your local orthodox rabbi. I took the liberty of editing your question to depersonalize it, if you want to change it back, or change it in any other way, just [edit](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/71245/edit) it.

Comment: Is there any reason to assume that the coke contained chametz? It should be noted that _kitnoyot_ which some Jews avoid consuming on Pesach, is not chametz, and may be owned over Pesach.

Comment: So although it is not eaten over Pesach, it is fine to consume afterwards?

Comment: Yes. assuming that there is no chametz in the coke. Hopefully someone will post a more thorough answer.

Comment: Is there something specific about *Diet* Coke that prompts the question?  Regular Coke usually contains *kitniyot* so I could see the question there, but I thought Diet Coke didn't use corn syrup and instead used artificial sweeteners?

Comment: An additional heter would be that one bought the diet coke before passover and the kitniyos was batel

Comment: You can have your "coke" and eat it too!

Comment: @sam that would be a heter for drinking the coke on pesach, but you don't need it to drink the coke after pesach. there is no prohibition to won kitniyos on pesach, and certainly no prohibition to consume kitniyos after pesach

Comment: Ofcourse,I also meant even if there was chametz

Comment: Side note, vending machines are often owned and operated by an outside third vendor. Still a valid question though.

Comment: @MonicaCellio *forehead slap* why didn't I think of that?

Comment: @Salmononius2 If the vending machine is owned by a 3rd party who is non-Jewish, then there's no problem, unless the Jew receives a percentage of the chametz items sold during Pesach. Even with that, if the diet Coke was Chametz, and sitting in the vending machine after Pesach, it obviously was not sold, and the Jew had no profit from that item. It does raise a separate question on what constitutes ownership in this case.

Answer (score 4):

Sidestepping the issue as to whether or not diet soda uses artificial sweeteners or corn syrup, lets go with the assumption that it's corn syrup.

Yes you can drink it, because corn (and its derivatives) isn't actual chametz, so there is no obligation to sell it during Passover. Therefore a can of soda is permissible even if it wasn't sold during Passover.

Source: [Halachipedia on Kitniyot](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Kitniyot)

As to whether or not there might be some secret ingredient that is potentially chametz. This isn't an issue as the halakha is very clear. Once something becomes non-edible, it loses its status as food and can therefore be added to food and consumed, even if it came from a totally non kosher source. [Therefore pig gelatin can be consumed, even with dairy.](http://ohr.edu/ask_db/ask_main.php/127/Q1/) These "secret ingredients" or flavorings, [are also not food.](http://kashrut.org/forum/viewpost.asp?mid=13403&highlight=) While there are stricter opinions that disagree with these halakhot, it does not take away from the fact that one will have very large poskim to rely upon, such as the Shulchan Arukh (YD 99). Most Kashrut agencies have policies in place to not follow these halakhot, but the actual halakha remains the same, despite their own internal policies.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39864/discussion-on-answer-by-aaron-may-one-drink-diet-coke-owned-by-a-jew-and-not-sol).